# Wait until a subscribe is called in angular

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt, angular-router-guards

Good morning,
I created an angualr app and I need to check users role in routing.
I created a service "RoleGuardService" with a method canLoad that read the JWS token and check the user permission:

```
import * as JWT from 'jwt-decode';
...
   const tokenPayload: App = JWT(token);
   if(tokenPayload.UserType == expectedRole){
      return true;
   }
   return false;
```

So far so good, but this force me to declare the permission hard coded:

`{ path: 'xxx', component: yyy, canLoad: [RoleGuardService], data: { expectedRole: 'Admin' } },`

Is possible to create a method that requires authorization directly from the web API?
like:

```
    var isAllowed = false;
    this.http.get('https://xxx/check_user/').subscribe(result: bool) => {
        isAllowed = result;
    }
    ///wait until the subscribe is called
    return isAllowed;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **canActivate** parameter for **route** from Core angular which has been created for that type of usecase https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

exmaple:

```
  {
    path: 'protectedRoute',
    component: SecureComponent,
    data: {
      authorities: ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    },
    canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
  }





@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserRouteAccessService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private accountService: AccountService,
  ) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    const authorities = route.data['authorities'];
    return this.accountService.identity().pipe(
      map(account => {
        if (!account) {
          return false;
        }

        if (!authorities || authorities.length === 0) {
          return true;
        }

        const hasAnyAuthority =   authorities.some((authority: string) => account.authorities.includes(authority));
        if (hasAnyAuthority) {
          return true;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['accessdenied']);
        return false;
      })
    );
  }

}
```

where AccountService is your service to get current login user

Answer (score 0):

You can make canLoad to return Observable of type boolean (`Observable<boolean>`)and return something like -

```
return this.http.get('https://xxx/check_user/').map(result => result);
```